# Turn-off gradient fill in all shapes in PowerPoint document (including groups and sub groups)

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to turn off gradient fill in all shapes in a PowerPoint document (including groups and sub groups).

The thing is I can't even get to cycle through the shapes correctly

```
Sub solid()

Set myDocument = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
For Each sh In myDocument.Shapes
    sh.Fill.solid
Next

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: your code works for me. Try to "Dim sh As Shape" at the beginning. edit: do you receive an error or what happens?

Comment: @smartini I Dimed and it didn't work.  After selecting a shape that has a gradient I run the code and nothing happens - the color doesn't change to solid.  I get no macro error.

Comment: is there actually a gradient in the shapes? see here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/add-a-gradient-color-to-a-shape-11cf6392-723c-4be8-840a-b2dab4b2ba3e

Comment: in VBA editor activate the immediate windows and in your For loop insert "debug.print sh.Name" - what do you see?

Comment: @smartini I get the names of the shapes on the first slide.  it seems to be working but only on the first slide.

Comment: then also loop through each slide. I pasted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub solid()
    Dim mydocument As Presentation
    Set mydocument = ActivePresentation
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim sl As Slide
    For Each sl In mydocument.Slides
        For Each sh In sl.Shapes
            If HasGradient(sh) = True Then
                sh.Fill.solid
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

And also implement this function from TheSpreadSheetGuru to check whether the shape has a gradient value.

```
Function HasGradient(shp As Shape) As Boolean
    'PURPOSE: Determine if a shape object contains a gradient format property
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault
    
    Dim GradientStopCount As Long
    
    'Test for Gradient Stops
      On Error Resume Next
      GradientStopCount = shp.Fill.GradientStops.Count
      On Error GoTo 0
    
    'Results
      If GradientStopCount <> 0 Then
        HasGradient = True
      Else
        HasGradient = False
      End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @smartini.  I get a runtime error on line sh.Fill.Solid 'The specified value is out of range'

Comment: what is the error number? is there any protected slide?

Comment: It runs through about 20 slides. Error is on one that has lines.

Comment: Error number -2147024809 (80070057)

Comment: I edited my answer and added a check function also into it. Make sure you have the updated version of the Sub solid()